# How is simulation used to check differences of regression techniques

Tags: bootstrap, simulation, count-data

I was reading a paper on Bootstrapping with models for count data. (Page 1170)

www.researchgate.net/publication/51738951_Bootstrapping_with_Models_for_Count_Data                         www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22023684

On the paper the author uses the conventional MLE to fit Poisson models but also uses some bootstrap technique to fit the same model (Re-samples the observations 5000 times).

The bootstrap technique gives larger standard errors for the estimates than the conventional method. The author then goes ahead to state that;

"A simulation analysis was conducted to check the differences in the results from the study. In total 1000 sets of data similar to the observed data were simulated..........."

The author then says that a model is then fit (using the simulation) and the results shows that standard errors from the conventional analysis was 3% too low.

My questions:

1. Could it men that data that results from simulation is the real/actual data so that we can use it to compare performance of the original observed data and that from bootstraps?
2. The observed data has 287 observations, how can we obtain "1000 sets of data" by simulation, because I thought that could be bootstrapping again.
3. What could have been the method used to run the simulated  "1000 sets of data"?

Comment: I have not read the article and if it does not explain, how exactly these 1000 data set were computed, then that is bad. You could, of course, simulate 1000 data sets that are similar based on the coefficents gained in your MLE-Poisson regression. That would be an obvious way to simulate data without bootstrapping.

Comment: Yes the data is simulated from the coefficients! But the paper reads "1000 sets of data" not "1000 data set"? Could this be a mistake

Comment: If you know your coefficients (or their distribution) you could simulate 1000 data sets consisting of 287 observations each. What would "1000 data set" mean, anyways?